# JAXB not able to parse xinclude tag in xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to parse xml's under specific directory say test1. 
   Directory test1 have a.xml and child directory test2. Directory test2 have b.xml.

In a.xml, I have a entry

```
<xi:include href="test2/b.xml">
```

At run time, JAXB is not able to parse it and gives this object-tag as null. Though its not throwing any error.

Can anyone help me on this.